# how can i reload nova.conf without restarting openstack

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-nova

I hava to need to modify the openstack's conf, change the the settings of dnsmasq. It's very easy to reload the config file with restarting nova-network.  But, for some reason, I can't do that operation.

so would anyone know how to reload the nova.conf without restarting the openstack?

Also, i can make some changes using code-injections, like add an extension. But I still don't know how to add extension without restarting it?

Answer (score 0):

According to [OpenStack docs](https://docs.openstack.org/fuel-docs/newton/userdocs/fuel-user-guide/troubleshooting/restart-service.html), to restart Nova service on a controller node (without restarting the server) you should run:

```
# service nova-api restart
# service nova-cert restart
# service nova-compute restart
# service nova-conductor restart
# service nova-consoleauth restart
# service nova-novncproxy restart
# service nova-scheduler restart
# service nova-spicehtml5proxy restart
# service nova-xenvncproxy restart
```

On a compute node:

```
# service nov-compute restart
```